# c# Mvvm fill ObservableObject property with data from GET request

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

in my .Net Mvvm/MVC learning journey I stumbled upon another problem.

I'm trying to fill an ObservableObject property so I can bind it to my window or usercontrol. The property should get filled inside `private async void` that executes a GET request.

As you can't `await` methodes/functions inside a property, I tried to Fill the property inside the method. It's always giving a `NullReferenceException`.
After setting line-breaks and pressing F11 (step over) a lot of times I figured out everything is getting filled up properly except for the desired property `Events`.

**The flow is like this:**

1. you select a country -> selectedItem is bound to SelectedCountry
2. select a "province" -> selectedItem is bound to SelectedProvince
3. select a city -> selectedItem is bound to SelectedCity

Each of above properties trigger a method that communicates with my API, the API is for getting data out of my database and displaying/returning it. The `ObservableObject` properties "Country, Province, City" are set within these methodes that communicate with the API. Everything still works fine at this point.

When the `City` property is set, it calls a method `GetOrgsByCity()` which fills another ObservableObject property `Orgs`. In the setter of `Orgs`, `GetFacebookData(FB_IDS)` is called. This method requires a parameter which is of type `List<string>` and is a property returning a filterd list by LINQ. Everything is still working fine.

**Here comes the problem:**

In the `GetFacebookData(FB_IDS)` method I'm trying to fill an `ObservableObject` property named `Events`, the method executes a GET request to Facebook. The `IsSuccessStatusCode` equals `true` and everything gets filled properly except for the `ObservableObject` property `Events`.

I'm "converting" the result list (`List<FB> data`) with a `foreach` to get `Events` filled. When I run it, it breaks an throws a `NullReferenceException`.
It's saying that `Events` is null or something since the other variables are filled correctly.

**Does anyone have an idea for why the `Events` property shoots a `NullReferenceException` when attempting to fill it?**

The xaml (where it's bound):

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource PartOneVM}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30px" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30px" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="txbCountry" Style="{StaticResource InfoLabelCountry}" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboCountry" Style="{StaticResource CountryBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" DisplayMemberPath="En_name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txbGewest" Style="{StaticResource InfoLabelGewest}" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboGewest" Style="{StaticResource GewestBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding Provinces}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProvince}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txbCity" Style="{StaticResource InfoLabelCity}" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboCity" Style="{StaticResource CityBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Height="300px" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

The ViewModel **The problem happens here at the bottom**:

```
public class PartOneVM : ObservableObject, IPage
{
    #region props
    public string Name { get { return "Page One"; } }

    private ObservableCollection<Country> _countries;

    public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries
    {
        get { return _countries; }
        set { _countries = value; OnPropertyChanged("Countries"); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Province> _provinces;

    public ObservableCollection<Province> Provinces
    {
        get { return _provinces; }
        set { _provinces = value; OnPropertyChanged("Provinces"); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<City> _cities;

    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities
    {
        get { return _cities; }
        set { _cities = value; OnPropertyChanged("Cities"); }
    }
    private Country _selectedCountry;

    public Country SelectedCountry
    {
        get { return _selectedCountry; }
        set { _selectedCountry = value; GetProvincesByCountry(); OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCountry"); }
    }
    private Province _selectedProvince;

    public Province SelectedProvince
    {
        get { return _selectedProvince; }
        set { _selectedProvince = value; GetCitiesByProvince(); OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProvince"); }
    }
    private City _selectedCity;

    public City SelectedCity
    {
        get { return _selectedCity; }
        set { _selectedCity = value; GetOrgsByCity(); OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCity"); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Org> _orgs;

    public ObservableCollection<Org> Orgs
    {
        get { return _orgs; }
        set { _orgs = value; GetFacebookData(FB_IDS); OnPropertyChanged("Orgs"); }
    }
    public List<string> FB_IDS
    {
        get { if (Orgs == null) return null; return (from s in Orgs where s.CityID.Equals(SelectedCity.ID) select s.FB_ID).Distinct().ToList<string>(); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<FB> _events;
    public ObservableCollection<FB> Events
    {
        get { return _events; }
        set { _events = value; OnPropertyChanged("Events");  }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ctor
    public PartOneVM()
    {
        GetCountries();
    }
    #endregion

    #region methodes
    private async void GetCountries()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:58564/api/country");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Country>>(json);
            }
        }
    }
    private async void GetProvincesByCountry()
    {
        if (SelectedCountry != null)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:58564/api/province/GetProvincesByCountry/" + SelectedCountry.ID);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Provinces = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Province>>(json);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private async void GetCitiesByProvince()
    {
        if (SelectedCountry != null && SelectedProvince != null)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:58564/api/city/GetCitiesByProvince/" + SelectedCountry.ID + "/" + SelectedProvince.ID);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Cities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<City>>(json);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private async void GetOrgsByCity()
    {
        if (SelectedCountry != null && SelectedProvince != null && SelectedCity != null)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:58564/api/org/GetOrgsByCity/" + SelectedCountry.ID + "/" + SelectedProvince.ID + "/" + SelectedCity.ID);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Orgs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Org>>(json);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private async void GetFacebookData(List<string> fb_ids)
    {
        var l = fb_ids
       .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
       .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 50)
       .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
       .ToList();

        for (var i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
        {
            string ids = string.Join(",", l[i]);
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?ids=" + ids + "&fields=id,name,events.limit(60)&access_token=<acces_token>");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, FB>>(json);
                    List<FB> data = result.Select(item => item.Value).ToList();

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        foreach (FB item in data)
                        {
                            if (item != null)
                            {
                                Events.Add(item); // THROWS NullReferenceException !!!
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                 // error handling   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Since everything else works fine I don't think it to be necessary to include all models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first - do not use 'async void' ever  - that's only may be appropriate in  event handlers sometimes but not here. Use 'async Task' and than you will be able to use ContinueWith construction to call OnPropertyChanged after the GetFacebook method(or one of the other async methods) will really be finished.

Second - Events is throwing exception  because it's not initialized. You should change:

```
private ObservableCollection<FB> _events = new ObservableCollection<FB>();
```

And also do not forget to clear this list if you will call GetFacebookData again.

Comment: Thank you, the initialisation worked. I didn't think about that because all the other ObservableObjects didn't seem to need to get initilised before getting filled ... Also I started with a Async Task but got in trouble because it has to happen in a loop. I'll try again with the Task. Thank you

Comment: Would you know why my listbox stays empty eventho the property has a count of 61 ?

Comment: Which property? Events?

Comment: Yes, the listbox that has this property bound, stays empty